# View a sequence of images using Python and NumPy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library, multimedia

I am using python's pil library to display images. Now I have a sequence of frames to display as a video content. I have a `np.array` that contains the RGB values of all the frames.
Could not find a method similar to Mathlabs `implay` to display these frames.
I can use `imshow` in a loop, but thats would be very slow as I need to mention framerate.

Answer (score 3):

**Matplotlib animations** work well, and is easy to use.  For reasonable size images they typically run at 30fps, or around that.  Matplotlib 1.1+ has a nice new animation interface: here are some [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html) and a [tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).

Older versions of matplotlib aren't to hard to animate either (you basically just set the data directly and refresh the plot) but the animation depends a bit more on the backend, so you need to look for an appropriate example.

For a specific example, if `images` is your list of matplotlib images that you want to animate, you can simply do:

```
animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images, interval=50, blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)
```

This, btw, is taken from [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image2.html), if you want to also see the code that generates test images.  The code to animate is simply the line above.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a handy script that just suits your need. Try it out [here](https://github.com/bilylee/videofig)

An example to show lists of images in a directory will be

```
import os
import glob
from scipy.misc import imread

img_dir = 'YOUR-IMAGE-DIRECTORY'
img_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(video_dir, '*.jpg'))

def redraw_fn(f, axes):
    img_file = img_files[f]
    img = imread(img_file)
    if not redraw_fn.initialized:
        redraw_fn.im = axes.imshow(img, animated=True)
        redraw_fn.initialized = True
    else:
        redraw_fn.im.set_array(img)
redraw_fn.initialized = False

videofig(len(img_files), redraw_fn, play_fps=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to already have a working OpenCV install built with OpenEXR – which if you don’t, it’s at least as much of an irritating time-sink to rebuild OpenCV as e.g. compiling SciPy from source in the first place – but so if the library is already there and working, you can use the Python bindings to quickly<sup>**†**</sup> view images with only a little bit of boilerplate. From [this example](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html#opencv-and-openexr):

```
import OpenEXR, Imath, cv
filename = "GoldenGate.exr"
exrimage = OpenEXR.InputFile(filename)

dw = exrimage.header()['dataWindow']
(width, height) = (dw.max.x - dw.min.x + 1, dw.max.y - dw.min.y + 1)

def fromstr(s):
    mat = cv.CreateMat(height, width, cv.CV_32FC1)
    cv.SetData(mat, s)
    return mat

pt = Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT)
(r, g, b) = [fromstr(s) for s in exrimage.channels("RGB", pt)]

bgr = cv.CreateMat(height, width, cv.CV_32FC3)
cv.Merge(b, g, r, None, bgr)

cv.ShowImage(filename, bgr)
cv.WaitKey()
```

I believe the OpenCV matrix type implements the python interfaces for `memoryview` et al – don’t be scared off by those objects as they’re NumPy arrays with different socks on, if you will.

†) quickly, w/r/t both the developer sense of speed: you can use this stuff immediately instead of building SciPy addons or mucking about with the Python array view C interface; but also in the real sense, as everything that comprises the aforementioned stuff – the OpenCV matrix structs, their related Python C API underpinnings, the OpenEXR format, and the stock implementation of the interface to same – have been raked over the optimization coals for years, largely by notable and grant-backed squadrons of specialist scholar-nerds who know what they are doing in this arena.

Comment: wow! i was actually thinking there would a method to help me with that.. this does look scary!

Comment: Ahaha I didn’t mean to freak you out… I am familiar with OpenCV so this just looks like a grosser version of a NumPy recipe to me. It’s no scarier than any given route to your end; there are a whole bunch of ways to do this, no doubt – as far as I know they all involve roughly this amount of rigamarole regardless of context, like e.g. initializing an SDL surface from CTypes, or subclassing the QGraphicsView binding in a PyQt app, or invoking whatever requisite Byzantine mess of calls the Matplotlib equivalent recipe (as @tom10 alludes to in his answer)... Et cetera, ad nauseum. Yes!